# Typography is giving line breaks instead of aligning it in one row

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Material ui Typography` to display the content in `Chip`, but my contents are showing up in two different rows instead of one, i do not need line break. Below is my code

```
  <Typography className={classes.title} style={{ display: 'inline' }} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
      {chipName}
      <img src={chipIIcon} style={{ marginLeft: '90%' }} alt="chipIIcon" />
  </Typography>
```

What's wrong in my code and how can i show both `chipName` and `img` in same one row?

Comment: It's because of the `marginLeft` set on the image

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Yes, but removing it is aligning the image just beside the 'chipName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `marginLeft: 90%` by `float: right`:

```
<Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
  {chipName}
  <img src={chipIIcon} style={{ float: 'right' }} alt="chipIIcon" />
</Typography>
```

Or, you can change the display of `Typography` to `flex` and set `justifyContent` to `space-between` (Ideally you will be using classes instead of inline styling):

```
<Typography style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
  chipName
  <img src={"chipIIcon"} alt="chipIIcon" />
</Typography>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8wmxp)